# Jquery multiple toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to learn how to use jquery/animation and i got stuck. When i click on #menu1 the toggle show's up, but when i click on #menu2 it only covers #menu1.

My goal is to make #menu2 toggle and at the same time #menu1 dissapear instead of just covering it.

Thanks to the community for their guidance.

```
 **JQUERY**              


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu1").click(function(){
    $("#Accueil").animate({width: 'toggle'});
    });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu2").click(function(){
    $("#Events").animate({width: 'toggle'});

    });
    });
    </script>

**HTML CODE**
    <div id="body">
        <div id="Accueil">
        </div>
        <div id="Events">
        </div>

        <div id="MenuBar">
            <div id="menu1">
            </div>
            <div id="menu2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
**CSS**
#Accueil
    background-color: brown;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    border-radius: 3px;

#Events
    background-color: purple;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    border-radius: 3px;
```

Comment: This is called accordion..and you should follow a better HTML structure for that...Check my answer

Comment: Ok.. let me tell you a few things .. 1st: just use one $(document).ready() and put all your code inside .. 2nd nothing over the world with width : 'toggle' ..  you can use .toggle()  or fadeToggle() or slideToggle();  or you can toggle between css classes by using toggleClass()

Comment: for jquery beginner , I highly recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZBkc4qS2IE&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810&index=36   Good Luck :)

Comment: i will check the youtube link thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <style>
      *{ margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box; list-style:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
      .accordion { width:500px; margin:15px 0 0 15px; background:#000; color:#fff; padding-right:10px;}
      .accordion ul li { border:1px solid #fff; margin-bottom:10px; padding:2px;}
      .accordion ul li a { color:#fff; display:block; }
      .accordion ul { padding:10px 0 10px 10px;}
      .accordion ul li ul { display:none;border-top:1px dotted #fff;}

      </style>


    <div class="accordion">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">1</a>
      <ul>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
      <li>1.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="#">2</a>
      <ul>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
      <li>2.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li>
    <a href="#">3</a>
      <ul>
      <li>3.1</li>
      <li>3.2</li>
      <li>3.3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    </ul>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.accordion li a').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){                 // check if current list is already open
    $(this).removeClass('clicked').next('ul').slideUp(500); // If yes then closes the current list
    }
    else{
    $('.accordion li a').removeClass('clicked').next('ul').slideUp(500);  // Remove the Clicked class from all anchors and Slide Up All ULs
    $(this).addClass('clicked').next('ul').slideDown(500);  // add clicked class to clicked anchor and slide Down its next UL
    }
    })

    });

    </script>
```